# PHP - Convert Currency Code to Name

Tags: php, currency

I have a list of 160 Currency codes (INR, USD etc) and I want convert them to their name like Indian National Rupees, United States Dollars etc... with PHP

Is this possible with a function/API or do I have to manually add the names manually?

Comment: Someobody already did it, manually: https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/2973986 :)

Comment: This is not a bad question at all, and I do not see why some people thinks this is BAD and down-vote?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the iso4217. There is a library you can use:
https://github.com/alcohol/iso4217/

Use it like:

```
<?php
$iso4217 = new Alcohol\ISO4217();

// from alpha3:
$details = $iso4217->getByAlpha3("USD");
print_r($details);
```